# escape special character in elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, sense, elasticsearch-py

My question is simple, I can't use @ in the search query. Finally, I found that I can escape the special characters using the backslash.

```
GET index/_search
{
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "\@as",
      "analyzer": "keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

But when I try to do that I got the following error `Unrecognized character escape '@' (code 64)\n at`. And when I try without @ symbol i got the results without @ symbol like

1. As missed as ever
2. As. GUI
3. As if
   And so on. can any one suggest how can I achieve the previous query can be executed as per my expectation?

I am using

- Elasticsearch 2.4.1
- Ubuntu 14.04
- Kibana 4.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because there is no need to escape the '@' character.
**`"query": "@as"`** should work.
You should check your mappings as well, if your fields are not marked as `not_analyzed`(or don't have `keyword` analyzer) you won't see any search results - standard analyzer removes characters like '@' when indexing a document.
UPDATE
`query_string` uses `_all` field by default, so you have to configure this field in the way similar to this example:

```
PUT index 
{
   "mappings":{
      "book":{
         "_all":{
            "type":"string",
            "index":"analyzed",
            "analyzer":"whitespace"
         },
         "properties":{
            "name":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

PUT /index/book/1
{
"name" : "@foo bar"
}

GET index/_search
{
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "@foo",
      "analyzer": "keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't create any mapping at all. I just store the values as it is. And I can see in kibana that the field is indexed and analyzed. So if it uses the standard analyzer and removes the character what should I do now to get my results.

Comment: if you need to have a possibility to search by special characters you need to change your mappings

Comment: what type of mapping is matched to my scenario? I am new to the es, So please elaborate the answer.

Comment: I am storing a million records per day. can you suggest me how to structure my index like many index or single index? Is there any problem will occur when I use a single index of for all of my data. what is the best practice?

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to blindly chose some approach without knowing how ES works. You can start with reading this chapter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scale.html